# Wrong GET variable after Mod Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with Mod Rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^page/([^-]*)/$ /showpage.php?id=$1 [L]
```

So when I type `example.com/page/` it goes to page.php and this is ok
but when I want go to `page/1/ (example.com/showpage.php?id=1)` and try to get
`$_GET['id']` variable it gives me back this

```
1.php/1
```

Comment: Consider adding `[L]` for your first rule and reorder them.

Comment: May I add it as an answer? (Would it be ok by you?)

Comment: Yes sure :) I wanted to upvote you but didnt know how since its my first time here...

Answer (score 1):

What's happening:

1. `/page/1/` : *(first rule matches)* rewrite to`/page/1.php`
2. `/page/1.php` : *(second rule matches)* rewrite to `/showpage.php?id=1.php`

To avoid it:

- you have to add a `[L]` flag after your first rule too.
- you can use a better pattern. For instance `[^/]+` which
  means `at least one character which is not a slash` (will prevent
  rules conflict in your case).
- you can check if files exist (not mandatory, but better).

This should be working as expected

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```